# Xcode - Save sqlite3 database in Library folder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite, bundle

I'm developing a app that use a Sqlite3 database. For now the db is inside app package, but I know that I'll have problems to update the data when I test in real world, with a real iPhone.

1 - How can I copy, at bundle phase, my project database to Library folder?

2 - How can I access this copied database? For now my code is:

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDatabase.sqlite"];
    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
```

What I'll have to change?

3 - How can I preserve this database (with the user's data) if I update the app?

Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to copy the database from the Resources folder to Documents folder

```
sqlite3 *database;
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Lists.db"];
success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
// The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
if(!success)
{
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Lists.db"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        TFLog(@"Failed moving database... %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        return;
    }
}
```

When you update your app database in your Documents folder will be their you just need to  check the condition

```
     success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
if it does not exits new database will be copied their.
Just keep in mind database structure is same as before.
```

Comment: You can also turn on `UIFileSharingEnabled` so you can copy the file off the iPhone via iTunes.

Comment: Thank you! I'm analyzing your code, and I have some questions: First, the code checks if the database exists in resourcePath. Should I verify the Documents folder instead? The DB will be safe in the Documents folder? And where is the statement writableDBPath?